# Is there a keyboard shortcut to refocus the cursor from the comment bubble to the document in MS-Word for Mac (2011)

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2011

When editing in MS-Word for Mac (2011), I can open a new comment with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

However, when I am finished typing the comment, I have to go back to the mouse to click on the document to refocus the cursor on the document.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will toggle between the comment bubbles and the main document so that I can add comments without using the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key works for me. <sub>(Not sure whether this qualifies as a full-fledged answer. ;)  )</sub>